# Is there a css attribute to specify a background color for a LinkButton's up state?

Tags: css, apache-flex

There are styles for over and clicked but no up state.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the upSkin style or the skin style to define the background of a button

So, instead of referencing the downSkin, or overSkin, or disabledSkin, you would just reference 'skin' or upSkin.

I believe you'll need an actual skin, and not an image to accomplish this, though.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/skins_styles.html

Comment: So how would i reference skin to a png I have?

Comment: Embed the png. http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=embed_4.html then just specify that class as the style you want.  Then something like setStyle('skin', myEmbeddedAsset); .  I think you're going to have to use a formal skin created in Flash to change the background, though.